# How to convert wint_t to char when given the target encoding?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Having `wint_t` Unicode code point got from the `getwc(fh)`. Using Windows functions, how can I convert it to the narrow `char` when I know the target encoding? I know that the character can be represented using the 8-bit encoding (say `windows-1250`).

Compared with the `WideCharToMultiByte()` function, is there a similar function to convert a single wide character instead of the string? How it should be done correctly?

This question is related to my [How to process CSV lines with nul char in some elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35553999/1346705)

Comment: That sounds like what I did in ncurses.  It's reasonably straightforward, so you might want to refine your question to focus on some aspect which is an impediment.

Comment: On Windows, neither `wint_t` nor `wchar_t` are capable of holding a Unicode code *point* (which would require >= 24 bit), since `wchar_t` is only 16 bit. They can hold *UTF-16* code *units*, which is a different thing. Code points beyond the Basic Multilingual Plane would require *two* code units (surrogate pair).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt but many compilers/STDlib implementation still don't have proper and complete implementation

Comment: This is not possible in general. Some Unicode code points convert to two `char`s. For example, in CP936, all the Chinese characters occupy two `char`s.

Comment: @DevSolar: You are right. I have restricted the question to the special case of Windows and its UTF-16 representation. I need that only to solve the case when the user can choose the export of the processed file (generated by the Windows application) or the 8-bit encoding in the human language or in UTF-16.

Comment: @pepr: I am referring to your use of "code point" in the first line of your question. In Unicode, "code point" and "code unit" are well-defined terms, and a Windows `wint_t` *cannot* hold a "code point"; it can only hold a UTF-16 "code unit", of which you might need *two* to encode a given "code point" if it is beyond the BMP (i.e., `\U00010000` through `\U0001FFFF`). You might also note that UTF-8 is *also* 8-bit... and really the encoding you *should* use for text files. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: OK, then what the `getwc()` actually returns? I understand that the Windows wchar_t is not capable to capture all Unicode characters. Does not it also mean that the *code point* in Windows is actually (only a bit crippled) code point anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no equivalent function, by design. You're mistakingly assuming it's even possible to convert letter by letter. That's about as impossible as translating English to French letter by letter - it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: I have added the assumption that I know the target encoding and that it is the 8-bit encoding. Having a Unicode code point--that is the reference to the exact character--and knowing the 8-bit encoding, the conversion of a single character or is possible or it fails because the character cannot be represented in the target encoding. Where is the mistake?

Comment: @pepr: U+004C U+0327 is a sequence of two Unicode code points which converts to `char(0xC8)` in CP-1250.

Comment: @pepr: MSalters gave the wrong sequence; should have been U+0043 U+030C. That is **also** the `Č` character... combining diacritics and decomposed form FTW.

Comment: My bad indeed, U+0043 U+0327 is `char(0xC7)`  and  U+0043 U+030C is `char(0xC8)`.

Comment: I see. I did not think about the composed characters. I am dealing with the UTF-16 content generated on Windows for Windows using probably a native MS functions. My guess is that the files do not use composed characters and the MS implementation of `getwc` returns the code point of the character (not composed) even though not all code points (as Unicode abstract values) can be stored in `wchar_t` (or their integer representation in `wint_t`).

Comment: @pepr: The `wchar_t` size isn't an issue for you; all character of CP-1250 are in the Unicode BMP (iow, fit in 16 bits). However, "generated by native Windows function" means that your code could break on a Windows upgrade, or a different Windows version.